# Schedule tasks with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

My scenario is the following: I have users who have to do tasks and after they did their job, they set status of task to completed. The owner is responsible to check these tasks which are completed and it can be done by manually, but it would be nice to have some automation to do this: e.g after 3 days the time of completion it should do it automacially.

I have multiple groups where I have to this automation.

So far what I found is: Quartz, but I'm not sure if this really needed to this kind of tasks and I feel like it's a bit overkill. Are there any options regarding to this? Is Quartz effective with large number of jobs like this?

Comment: Why dont you use spring batch? Spring Boot provides a spring-boot-starter-batch dependency. https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch

Comment: Could you be more specific? Unfortunately, I didn't find any guideto how achieve to schedule Batch jobs at a give date

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ has got samples. You can add specific time/date like this  @Scheduled(cron="0 30 16 * * *"). More here https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions.